# Facebook apps: Redirect to canvas iframe to URL within app (not main app page)

Tags: facebook, redirect, canvas

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK; setting up an app on Facebook.
I need the app to run within Canvas only, so if the user goes to this url, for example:
http://{site_url}/fbapp/index.php?this=that&that=this&etc=1

I want to:
a) redirect using javascript to the canvas page (ie. http://apps.facebook.com/appname/) and then
b) the iframe must go directly to the page within the app (ie. index.php?this=that&that=this&etc=1)

I've googled this to the moon but not getting anywhere!

Any ideas??

I've tried this:

```
var currlocation = location.href;
if ( window.self === window.top && !currlocation.match('facebook') ) {
location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<?= $facebook->getAppID() ?>&redirect_uri=<?= $site_url; ?>?<?= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>'; }
```

It results in an indefinite redirect loop between the site and facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of -

> location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=getAppID() ?>&redirect_uri=?';

Use-

```
header("Location: CANVAS_URL");
exit;
```

Comment: You can't use PHP, as only Javascript can detect if the page is in a frame I think?

I figured out that you can actually just go to http://apps.facebook.com/appname/index.php?this=that&that=this&etc=1

Was overthinking things obviously!